# Image scaledown not working in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have this code in my html :

```
<img src="images/amazon.png" width="40px" />
```

The image is originally 110 by 80, but I am scaling it down to 40px wide. This works fine in chrome and firefox, scaling it down to 40 by 15.

[image]

But in IE9/10 it still shows the original size i.e. 110 by 80.

[image]

Why is this happening, and how do I resolve this ?

Comment: scales for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/T6CPz/ , btw those attributes are deprecated, use CSS or inline styles instead

Comment: Ok, so I have twitter bootstrap.css included in my file which was causing the above 'resize to original' issue. Removing that resolves it. And I found that `width` and `height` for an `img` are set to `auto` in bootstrap.css. Removing those properties resolves it. Can someone explaing why that happened ?

Comment: Alien .. can you provide a link that says that ?

Comment: @Mr.Alien Going by the HTML5 draft spec, the width and height attributes are not deprecated for `img`, `iframe`, `embed`, `object`, `video` and `input`s of type="image"

Comment: @soundswaste CSS specifications of dimensions take priority over those specified in the attributes.  With CSS specifying `auto`, things can get interesting when you try to use width and height attributes as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the old-style HTML attributes to specify `width`, etc, the syntax does **not** include `px`. It needs to be:

```
<img src="images/amazon.png" width="40" />
```

However, it is considered bad practice to use these attributes these days -- they are deprecated in favour of CSS styles.

CSS can be specified in the element, so if you need to specify it there, you would write is as follows:

```
<img src="images/amazon.png" style="width:40px;" />
```

Note that since this is CSS styling, the `px` is required here.

Even better would be to specify the width in a separate CSS file (alongside the rest of your page layout styles).